# Retrieve error message string in C in MEX file

Tags: matlab, mex

The [`mexCallMATLABWithTrap`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexcallmatlabwithtrap.html) function can return an `MException` object.  What can I do with this object (`mxArray`) from within C?  In particular, is it possible to extract the message string from it as an `mxChar`, from within C code?

The [matrix API](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/access-data.html) has functions for accessing all data types, including structures, *except* objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution I found is to call [`getReport`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getreportmexception.html) using `mexCallMATLAB`, and pass the exception object to it.  It will return an `mxArray` of Char type containing the message.

Example with using `mexCallMATLABWithTrap` to call `evalc`:

```
// cmd is an mxArray * of Char type; it's the input to evalc
mxArray *res;
err = mexCallMATLABWithTrap(1, &res, 1, &cmd, "evalc");
if (err != NULL) {
    // err is now an MException
    mxArray *msg;
    mexCallMATLAB(1, &msg, 1, &err, "getReport");
    // assert(mxIsChar(msg));
    const mxChar *str = mxGetChars(msg);
}
```

One problem with this that I couldn't solve yet is that the message string will include: "Error in evalc" seemingly regardless of where the problem happened.